# Great Plain Stored Procedure [taSopLineIvcInsert] Error 5313

Tags: dynamics-gp

Sql procedure error codes returned:
Error Number = 5313  Stored Procedure taSopLineIvcInsert  Error Description = Unit of Measure does not exist for the Unit of Measure Schedule being used
Node Identifier Parameters: taSopLineIvcInsert
SOPNUMBE = FXINV17-0183253
SOPTYPE = 3
Related Error Code Parameters for Node : taSopLineIvcInsert
NONINVEN =  Note: This parameter was not passed in, no value for the parameter will be returned. 
UOFM = EA

```
<taSopLineIvcInsert>
   <SOPTYPE>3</SOPTYPE>
   <SOPNUMBE>FXINV17-0183253</SOPNUMBE>
   <CUSTNMBR>CCT-136</CUSTNMBR>
   <DOCDATE>26/9/2017</DOCDATE>
   <ITEMNMBR>DVG-013</ITEMNMBR>
   <UNITPRCE>30.00000</UNITPRCE>
   <QUANTITY>1.00000</QUANTITY>
   <ITEMDESC>DRIED MUSHROOM</ITEMDESC>
   <DOCID>STDINV         </DOCID>
   <DEFEXTPRICE>1</DEFEXTPRICE>
   <UOFM>EA</UOFM>
</taSopLineIvcInsert>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The error message is coming from the Microsoft Dynamics GP eConnect
>   API.   eConnect stored procedure taSopLineIvcInsert, performs
>   validation on the data to ensure the imported transaction complies
>   with the Dynamics GP business rules.
>
> The 5313 error is indicating that the UOM Schedule assigned to item
>   DVG-013 does not contain the Unit of Measure value of "EA" that was
>   passed in with the SOP transaction.
>
> Please login to Dynamics GP, open the Item Maintenance window, select
>   item DVG-013, and then check the UOM Schedule ID assigned to that
>   item.  Then click on the UOM Schedule ID link and review the list of
>   acceptable values for that UOM Schedule.  You may see a value of
>   "Each", but not "EA".